# Dealing with a method that throws exceptions while trying to keep performance up

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, try-catch

I am writing an application that requires me to loop through a list of members/users in a ASP.NET web site.  I am calling a method that can throw an exception that is out of my control.

Here is a snippet:

```
foreach(var member in members)
{
    memberExport.Groups = GetGroups(member);
}
```

Here is GetGroups

```
protected string[] GetGroups(Member member)
{
    try
    {
        return Roles.GetRolesForUser(member.LoginName);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return new string[] { "" };
    }
}
```

Roles.GetRolesForUser can throw three different exceptions but if an exception is thrown I don't want the whole application to stop running, I just want to carry on to the next member.

The **Problem** is *try and catch* is expensive on performance and it is taking a considerable amount of time compared to when I run it without try and catch.

How can I do this without the hit on performance?

***My solution based on the answer/s provided:***

```
protected string[] GetRolesForUser(Member member)
{
    if(Membership.GetUser(member.LoginName) != null && member.LoginName != "")
        return Roles.GetRolesForUser(member.LoginName);

    return new string[0];
}
```

Funny enough, this is giving me similar timings to what I had originally.

Comment: Is that really a bottleneck? did you run profiler on that?

Comment: Do you have access to the `GetRolesForUser` code? You should change that method, so that it doesn't throw exceptions, but returns an empty string instead. That way, you don't have to check the result later.

Comment: Yeah I had the process completing in 4 minutes but now I have been waiting 15 minutes.  The only update was to add the try and catch around the method.  It's very strange.

Comment: That makes no sense - exception handling shouldn't add anything like that much overhead. If you didn't have the try/catch in your first timings, how did you handle the exceptions in order to do the timings? I'm suspicious that the way you are working out your times is not comparable. Exactly *what* exceptions are you seeing? And are you sure you need to return `new string[]{""};` rather than `new string[0];`?

Comment: Thats fine, I can return new string[0] but this obviously isn't the issue.  I am seeing ArgumentNullException on a few members where member does not exist.  These members are obsolete members from when the system was built.  I have come up with a solution which I will add to me question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h930x07.aspx), following exceptions are thrown by this method:

- `System.ArgumentNullException` when username is null
- `System.ArgumentException` when username contains comma
- `System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException` when role management is not enabled

I think you can easily deal with them:

```
protected string[] GetGroups(Member member)
{
    string login = member.LoginName;

    if (login == null || login.Contains(",") || !Roles.Enabled)
        return new [] { "" };    

    return Roles.GetRolesForUser(login);    
}
```